# Beautiful String

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Got this question from a [here](http://learn.hackerearth.com/forum/70/beautiful-unique-strings/). But the runtime of the algorithm which i could figure out was really bad. Here is the question:

> String s is called unique if all the characters of s are different.
>   String s2 is producible from string s1, if we can remove some
>   characters of s1 to obtain s2.
>
> String s1 is more beautiful than string s2 if length of s1 is more
>   than length of s2 or they have equal length and s1 is
>   lexicographically greater than s2.
>
> Given a string s you have to find the most beautiful unique string
>   that is producible from s.
>
> Input: First line of input comes a string s having no more than
>   1,000,000(10^6) characters. all the characters of s are lowercase
>   english letters.
>
> Output: Print the most beautiful unique string that is producable from
>   s
>
> Sample Input: babab
>
> Sample Output: ba

What i did is this:

1. Take the string and remove all equal adjacent characters with single one.    Example: input: "bbbbbab" output: "bab", this is the output of this step. Which becomes the input to next steps.
2. Now build an array for each unique character in the string. This array will have the indexes of its occurrence in the given input array.
3. Note the first occurence of each element. Find min and max of the occurences. Using this iterate over all possible strings which can be formed with words ending at index max. Take the lexicographically greatest.
4. Repeat the above by moving max.

I want a correct and efficient algorithm which can scale when the input string is really big.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a set of [implementations](https://github.com/rdasxy/beautiful-strings) if those are too inefficient, fork the repo and make them more efficient.

Comment: Unfortunately the solution mentioned in the link is wrong, i tried implementing it myself.. try input "abcdefabdc" output should be "bcefad", algorithm given in the link returns "bcdefa"..

Comment: Answer seems to be "efadbc", solution in this link seems to be correct [link](http://skilldrill.wordpress.com/2013/06/28/beautiful-unique-strings/)

Comment: seems it's wrong, given "acaumbdplfenoqracedrfg", answer should be "umbplnoqracedfg" but result of its python code is "cumbdplfenoqrag"

Comment: @McGar maybe fork it and fix it?  It isn't my repo fwiw

Answer (score 1):

Here is the program to find Beautiful substring.It is fully optimized code which has less complexity using dynamic programming.

```
static String LCSubStr(String X,String Y, int m, int n)// Longest Common substring
{
      int LCSarr[][]=new int[m+1][n+1];
      int max = 0; 
      int max_index=0;
      for (int i=0; i<=m; i++)
      {
          for (int j=0; j<=n; j++)
          {
                if (i == 0 || j == 0)
                LCSarr[i][j] = 0;

                else if (X.charAt(i-1) == Y.charAt(j-1))//if char matches
                {
                     LCSarr[i][j] = LCSarr[i-1][j-1] + 1;
                     if(max < LCSarr[i][j])
                     {
                           max=LCSarr[i][j];
                           max_index=i; //Index points at which last char matched
                      }
                 }
                 else LCSarr[i][j] = 0;
           }
       }
       return (X.substring(max_index-max,max_index));

     }

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
             Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

             System.out.print("Enter String 1:  ");
             String str=new String(sc.nextLine());
             str=str.toLowerCase();
             String temp2="";//string with no duplicates
             HashMap<Integer,Character> tc = new HashMap<Integer,Character>();//create a hashmap to store the char's
             char [] charArray = str.toCharArray();
             for (Character c : charArray)//for each char
             {
                  if (!tc.containsValue(c))//if the char is not already in the hashmap
                  {
                       temp2=temp2+c.toString();//add the char to the output string
                       tc.put(c.hashCode(),c);//and add the char to the hashmap
                  }
              }
              System.out.print("\nBeatiful substring of given String is:  ");
              System.out.println(LCSubStr(str,temp2,str.length(),temp2.length()));//Find Longest common substring which gives us actually beautiful string
      }
```

Comment: @GeraldSchneider : Thank you for giving me a suggestion.I am trying to improve my answer given above as per your suggestion.you are most welcome for further suggestion.